# How to parse JSON in a grails controller

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy

I'm submitting a form via jQuery and I'm sending a JSON object along with the submission. I'm doing this like so:

```
    console.log(jsonObject)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myapp/mycontroller/save",
        data: jsonObject,
        success: '',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

the `console.log` output looks like this:

```
Object {test: Object, test2: Object}
test: Object
   red: "off"
   green: "off"
   yellow: "off"
test2: Object
   red: "on"
   green: "on"
   yellow: "off"
```

In my controllers save action right now I just have

```
def save() {
  println params
}
```

which prints this:

> [test2[red]:on, test[green]:off, test2[yellow]:on, test2[red]:off,
>   test[green]:off, test[yellow]:off, action:save,
>   controller:mycontroller]

**Question**

How can I access the `jsonObject` and parse it in my `save()`

Comment: Try JSON.parse : http://mike.bailey.net.au/2011/02/json-with-ruby-and-rails/

Comment: this is in grails. plus I'm not sure what to put here `JSON.parse(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can access it just as object:

`params.test.red` (which is "off")

Comment: i want to be able to iterate over all the keys in it

Comment: It's a map, so you can iterate through it with "each" closure, for example, or with "for" loop: for (e in params){ /*Do smth with e*/ }